# Swift 4 and iOS 11: One transparent NavigationBar using NavigationController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a NavigationController and two Pages (HomePage, DetailPage) with each NavigationItem (automatically added when using NavigationController).

On the DetailPage i want to present a different NavigationBar (with an Image) as using on the HomePage (Text and BarTintColor)

So how can i change only the NavBar on the DetailPage, when using a NavigationController?

I found this Code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .red
}
```

Will this work, if i paste that Code in the DetailViewController class? Is that all I have to do?

Thanks for your answer

Comment: What happened when you tried pasting the code in `DetailViewController` ?

Comment: I haven't had the chance to test it yet. I asked the question in the hope that someone could already answer me or have already gained experience with it... i will answer you, if i tried that.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri the code is the solution to solve the problem